# How to make footer stick to bottom (not fixed)?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'ma having trouble making the footer stick to the bottom. I don't want to make it fixed, I want it to stay at the bottom and not move when I scroll.

I found a solutions with bootstap but that messes up the order of the items on the page. I want the entire page to stay the way it is, just keep the footer at the bottom of the screen.

What I'm I doing wrong?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

footer {
    background-color: #f4e6f5;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<body>

    <nav class="navigationBar">

        <img class="logoImg" src="photos/logo.png" alt="logo">

        <h1 class="col-md-9">Japan Store</h1>

    <div class="mediaIcons col-md-1">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-square btn--facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram-square btn--instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter-square btn--twitter"></i>
    </div>

</nav>

<nav class="filterContainer m-5 p-5 float-left d-flex flex-column shadow col-md-2 col-9">

    <h2 class="pb-4">Filtrar Items</h6>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="todo" name="Todo" value="Todo">
            <label for="todo">Todo</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="bebidas" name="bebidas" value="Bebidas">
            <label for="bebidas">Bebidas</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="snacks" name="snacks" value="Snack">
            <label for="snacks">Snacks</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="golosinas" name="golosinas" value="Golosinas">
            <label for="golosinas">Golosinas</label>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="filterButton btn btn-outline-dark mt-5">Filtrar</button>

</nav>

<div class="itemsContainer float-right col-md-9">
    <div class="row">

    <! -- The next code repeats 15 times (store items) -->
    
    <div class="itemBox p-4">
        <div class="card h-100 shadow">

            <img class="card-img-top" src="photos/Befco Kuriyama Bakauke Rice Crackers Hokkaido Corn.jpg" alt="..."/>

            <div class="card-body p-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h5>Befco Kuriyama Bakauke Rice Crackers</h5>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    </div>

                    <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through"></span>
                    $18.00

                </div>
            </div>
          
              <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="#">Agregar al carrito</a></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<div>

    <footer class="col-md-12">
        <p>This is my footer</p>
    </footer>
    
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Wrap the top content in a div and give it a height and make sure `overflow: auto` in your CSS for that div. Give your footer a height as well. These 2 heights should add up to the height that you choose - if it should be relative to the parent, you can use `calc` in CSS to base it off that. Another alternative is to use a flex or grid layout in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

without using position fixed you could use position absolute on the footer and relative on the body

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: relative; /*new
height: 100vh /*new

footer {
background-color: #f4e6f5;
height: 5rem;
width: 100%;
position: absolute; /*new
bottom: 0; /*new
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a section to wrap the body content just for simplicity. And added some CSS to make the footer stick to bottom without scrolling or overlapping the content.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px); /*new*/
}
section {  
  overflow-x: hidden; /*new*/
  height: calc(100vh - 100px); /*new*/
}

footer {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.05);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /*new*/
    bottom: 0; /*new*/
    overflow: hidden; /*new*/
 }
```

```
<body>
<section>
...content...
</section>
```

I hope it helps!

[image: working example]

Comment: Title of the question says "not fixed".